# .htpasswd Problems

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have setup an .htaccess and .htpasswd file correctly and my password gets accepted, but only on the **second** attempt. I have read somewhere what to do about this, but I lost the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, after reading a separate article on this site, I have no XML and no SWF loading. Al least I don't think so. Its www.chunkydesign.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you refer to the domain differently in several locations. For example, if you refer to your site as "http://mysite.com" and "http://**www**.mysite.com", you have to authenticate twice: once for each. If you refer to your site consistently in your code, you'll only be prompted once.

In addition, if you refer to any subdomains, such as "http://**es**.mysite.com" for a localized version of the site, you'd have to authenticate again for that reference.

Comment: Would it then make a difference if my .htaccess page telling it to authenticate was in a subdomain?

Comment: Also check the path. If you first authenticate at `http://www.example.com/somedir/thing`, the browser will only remember the credentials for other paths inside the `somedir` folder.

Comment: @William Hand: If you are authenticating on a sub-domain but your code has hard-coded references to the main site rather than relative references to the current sub-domain, you'd receive multiple prompts as well.